# CSharp error downloading files from s3 bucket: AWSSDK.S3.CodeAnalysis.dll could not be found

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am running the below code to download files from s3 bucket and the visual studio returns with no issues found. I installed nuget for awssdk.s3 and awssdk.core. My visual studio is 2019 and version 16.11.5. Microsoft .net framework version 4.8.04084. However when I build , it throws error as below. Any one has idea as to what could be the fix? I have researched and not able to come with a solution. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Error :
[image]

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       Metadata file '..\packages\AWSSDK.S3.3.7.101.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\AWSSDK.S3.CodeAnalysis.dll' could not be found   ST_35de80d034b24af7b858c7e96ac14399 C:\Windows\TEMP\Vsta\SSIS_ST130\Vsta3XuAb1HyMUSPUWmD_oVLkA\VstaCvKhS58I30S1_G1CbhqG2Q\CSC   0
```

AWSSDK.s3 properties :
[image]

AWSSDK.Core properties:
[image]

Code used :

```
//code below downloads the files from s3 bucket using all the aws credentials. bucket name, secret key and access key are provided although below code shows dummy keys. 

public void Main()
                {
                    
        //add code to download files from s3 bucket
                    var AwsImportFilePathParcel = "https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/my-bucket-name?region=us-east-2&tab=objects";
                    var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("myaccesskey", "mysecretkey");
        //setup region for the bucket
                    IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        //code to get the files from s3
                    S3DirectoryInfo info = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, "my-bucket-name", AwsImportFilePathParcel);
                    S3FileInfo[] s3Files = info.GetFiles(AwsImportFilePathParcel);
        //downloading the files from s3 bucket
                    foreach (var fileInfo in s3Files)
                    {
        //this downloads the files in s3bucket to the local directory
                        var localPath = Path.Combine("C://Users//Desktop/", fileInfo.Name);
        //copying the files to local directory
                         fileInfo.CopyToLocal(localPath);
                    }
        
                
                      Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
        
               
        
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try cleaning the project and then building again

Comment: Tried cleaning and building - spits out the same error.

Comment: Can you please make a public repository on Github with code that replicates the issue? Trying to rule out it being anything local, which sounds like it considering you cannot find anything online for it!